# Coerce mixed data types to binary values

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-structures

Input: `latent_representations_train_nmf` and `train_data_dict` are nested dictionaries that may contain `mutation_df` dataframe. The values of `mutation_df` can be of various types, such as float, binary, int64, or boolean.

Expected output: Coerce all values in `mutation_df` to binary, regardless of their original types and return as a nested list by concatenating the output of `mutation_df` with the remaining output.

Problem: My code returned float for output associated with `mutation_df`. I want binary values, not float.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# Create a list to store mixed representation data
mixed_representation_all_train = []

# Create separate lists for binary and float data
binary_array = None
float_arrays = []

# Concatenate latent representations for all datasets
for dataset, dataset_dict in latent_representations_train_nmf.items():
    for key, (data, _) in train_data_dict[dataset].items():
        truncated_key = key[:-3] if key.endswith('_df') else key  # Remove "_df" only if it's present

        # Check if mutation_df is present
        if truncated_key == 'mutation':
            # Coerce mutation_df to binary and store in the binary_array
            binary_array = data.to_numpy()
        else:
            # Store other float dataframes in the float_arrays list
            float_arrays.append((truncated_key, data.to_numpy()))

# Ensure all float arrays have the same number of rows
num_rows = len(binary_array) if binary_array is not None else len(float_arrays[0][1])

# Pad and concatenate float arrays if binary_array is not None
if binary_array is not None:
    float_arrays_padded = [
        (key, np.pad(array, ((0, num_rows - array.shape[0]), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan))
        for key, array in float_arrays
    ]

    # Check if any float arrays have a different number of columns
    unique_columns = set(array.shape[1] for _, array in float_arrays_padded)

    if len(unique_columns) == 1:
        float_arrays_padded = [array for _, array in float_arrays_padded]
        concatenated_array = np.rec.fromarrays([binary_array] + float_arrays_padded, names='binary,' + ','.join(train_data_dict[dataset][key][0].columns))
        mixed_representation_all_train = concatenated_array.to_list()
    else:
        # If all arrays are float, concatenate them directly
        mixed_representation_all_train = []
        for dataset, dataset_dict in latent_representations_train_nmf.items():
            for key, (data, _) in train_data_dict[dataset].items():
                truncated_key = key[:-3] if key.endswith('_df') else key  # Remove "_df" only if it's present
                mixed_representation_all_train.append(
                    np.concatenate([
                        dataset_dict[key],
                        encoder_models[dataset][key].predict(data),
                        train_data_dict[dataset][key][1]
                    ], axis=1)
                )
```

Input:

`latent_representations_train_nmf`

```
{'transcriptomics': {'transcriptomics_df': array([[0.864448  , 0.09106825],
         [0.0123347 , 0.675261  ],
         [0.68785916, 0.4070271 ],
         [0.84405358, 0.21946786]]),
  'mrna_deconv': array([[0.71182397, 0.49046602],
         [0.73725949, 0.09712671],
         [1.16152444, 0.13353929],
         [0.00343417, 1.11564544]])},
 'epigenomics': {'epigenomics_df': array([[0.57277066, 0.59834198],
         [1.09969277, 0.11959057],
         [0.27207849, 0.53464324],
         [0.01119349, 0.89636409]]),
  'meth_deconv': array([[0.13387474, 0.77731093],
         [0.65884812, 0.16525756],
         [0.85281024, 0.00124021],
         [0.33406365, 0.94603438]])},
 'proteomics': {'proteomics_df': array([[4.27433650e-01, 4.17119969e-01],
         [6.57250876e-02, 1.00090599e+00],
         [6.07513696e-01, 7.01521419e-04],
         [3.49968501e-01, 8.32643489e-01]])},
 'mutation': {'mutation_df': array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])}}
```

`val_data_dict`

```
{'transcriptomics': {'transcriptomics_df': (             gene_1    gene_2    gene_3    gene_4    gene_5    gene_6  \
   sample_1   0.691348  0.521166  0.459497  0.705347  0.382188  0.077001   
   sample_12  0.726720  0.495908  0.324347  0.168899  0.430455  0.362000   
   sample_24  0.598582  0.916310  0.853068  0.947954  0.986466  0.420796   
   sample_14  0.000000  0.780463  0.636086  0.985590  0.975761  0.864531   
   
                gene_7    gene_8    gene_9   gene_10  ...   gene_41   gene_42  \
   sample_1   0.837222  0.975583  0.499170  0.030487  ...  0.311226  0.934552   
   sample_12  0.976657  0.037110  0.348650  0.171984  ...  0.562045  0.598262   
   sample_24  0.471624  0.878787  0.973434  0.682812  ...  0.354657  0.682743   
   sample_14  0.495655  0.864957  0.000000  0.022025  ...  0.762790  0.073613   
   
               gene_43   gene_44   gene_45   gene_46   gene_47   gene_48  \
   sample_1   0.432117  0.264464  0.569987  1.000000  0.310993  0.000000   
   sample_12  0.479726  0.000000  0.941958  0.139163  0.100171  0.713167   
   sample_24  0.477398  0.922020  0.816585  0.561219  0.039741  0.269476   
   sample_14  1.000000  0.558949  0.496552  0.296456  0.519055  0.303284   
   
               gene_49   gene_50  
   sample_1   0.411976  0.270137  
   sample_12  0.393575  1.000000  
   sample_24  0.343165  0.659200  
   sample_14  0.488848  0.722761  
   
   [4 rows x 50 columns],
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1),
  'mrna_deconv': (           mrna_cell_type_1  mrna_cell_type_2  mrna_cell_type_3  \
   sample_1           0.394566          0.011921          0.000000   
   sample_12          0.404935          0.111799          0.966228   
   sample_24          0.560821          0.850768          0.670965   
   sample_14          0.960494          0.034538          0.179321   
   
              mrna_cell_type_4  mrna_cell_type_5  mrna_cell_type_6  \
   sample_1           0.714336          0.323245          0.028255   
   sample_12          0.000000          0.482947          0.345501   
   sample_24          1.000000          0.000000          0.402768   
   sample_14          0.029928          0.737408          0.371701   
   
              mrna_cell_type_7  mrna_cell_type_8  mrna_cell_type_9  \
   sample_1           0.808956          0.389801          0.412113   
   sample_12          0.232593          0.000000          0.486958   
   sample_24          0.932924          0.523272          0.691870   
   sample_14          0.729265          0.364867          0.157626   
   
              mrna_cell_type_10  mrna_cell_type_11  mrna_cell_type_12  \
   sample_1            0.068939           0.652612           0.363804   
   sample_12           0.034300           0.180022           0.166033   
   sample_24           0.717946           0.540615           0.085843   
   sample_14           0.114609           0.062716           1.000000   
   
              mrna_cell_type_13  mrna_cell_type_14  mrna_cell_type_15  \
   sample_1            1.000000           0.727775           0.582466   
   sample_12           0.565883           0.000000           0.092813   
   sample_24           0.454759           0.855966           0.978153   
   sample_14           0.983699           0.818914           0.930252   
   
              mrna_cell_type_16  mrna_cell_type_17  mrna_cell_type_18  \
   sample_1            0.858518           0.963238           0.313793   
   sample_12           0.121522           1.000000           0.876609   
   sample_24           0.720633           0.898638           0.561666   
   sample_14           0.036601           0.000000           0.030582   
   
              mrna_cell_type_19  mrna_cell_type_20  
   sample_1            0.470388           0.992411  
   sample_12           0.952872           0.716374  
   sample_24           0.604161           0.483300  
   sample_14           0.516435           0.820544  ,
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1)},
 'epigenomics': {'epigenomics_df': (           methyl_1  methyl_2  methyl_3  methyl_4  methyl_5  methyl_6  \
   sample_1   0.672154  0.744304  0.667775  0.390236  0.352767  0.802986   
   sample_12  0.544498  0.554213  0.965767  0.424389  0.601546  0.177557   
   sample_24  0.542240  0.886363  0.218744  0.479554  0.720351  0.258920   
   sample_14  0.150681  1.000000  0.183405  0.588811  0.037080  0.893361   
   
              methyl_7  methyl_8  methyl_9  methyl_10  ...  methyl_21  methyl_22  \
   sample_1   0.702764  0.103879  0.217496   0.746817  ...   0.503266   0.897453   
   sample_12  0.565769  0.084268  0.082026   1.000000  ...   0.654740   0.646928   
   sample_24  0.000000  0.348567  0.675022   0.254140  ...   0.604049   0.161800   
   sample_14  0.143029  0.804603  0.372704   0.063367  ...   0.658111   0.113772   
   
              methyl_23  methyl_24  methyl_25  methyl_26  methyl_27  methyl_28  \
   sample_1    0.681824   0.389858   1.000000   0.945965   0.893641   0.153304   
   sample_12   0.754017   0.626988   0.133138   0.999606   0.935700   1.000000   
   sample_24   0.787595   0.073253   0.464275   0.561728   0.197172   0.000000   
   sample_14   0.247114   0.507432   0.440542   0.644694   0.014094   0.470851   
   
              methyl_29  methyl_30  
   sample_1    0.000000   0.060569  
   sample_12   0.344208   0.988731  
   sample_24   0.722077   0.487402  
   sample_14   0.602050   0.471194  
   
   [4 rows x 30 columns],
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1),
  'meth_deconv': (           meth_cell_type_1  meth_cell_type_2  meth_cell_type_3  \
   sample_1           0.069553          0.253596          0.673022   
   sample_12          0.796670          0.703439          0.245398   
   sample_24          0.977351          0.577448          1.000000   
   sample_14          0.968739          0.201095          0.486083   
   
              meth_cell_type_4  meth_cell_type_5  meth_cell_type_6  \
   sample_1           0.837422          0.794271          0.261801   
   sample_12          0.671278          0.548693          0.129952   
   sample_24          0.268973          0.286052          0.130970   
   sample_14          0.859409          0.779962          0.675651   
   
              meth_cell_type_7  meth_cell_type_8  meth_cell_type_9  \
   sample_1           0.405700          0.582617          0.630832   
   sample_12          0.707981          0.359571          0.028506   
   sample_24          0.485974          0.816738          0.140384   
   sample_14          0.533937          0.969726          0.993525   
   
              meth_cell_type_10  meth_cell_type_11  meth_cell_type_12  \
   sample_1            0.113048           0.560970           0.893525   
   sample_12           0.348230           0.637327           0.023659   
   sample_24           0.743956           0.982004           0.020106   
   sample_14           0.109610           0.987293           0.556596   
   
              meth_cell_type_13  meth_cell_type_14  meth_cell_type_15  \
   sample_1            0.256618           0.596471           0.130487   
   sample_12           0.381113           0.128097           0.407463   
   sample_24           0.000000           0.087194           0.170633   
   sample_14           0.870240           0.733769           0.339111   
   
              meth_cell_type_16  meth_cell_type_17  meth_cell_type_18  \
   sample_1            0.296650           0.869589           0.594552   
   sample_12           0.829570           1.000000           0.566519   
   sample_24           0.801784           0.821255           0.222095   
   sample_14           0.617727           0.881807           0.047561   
   
              meth_cell_type_19  meth_cell_type_20  
   sample_1            0.608905           0.263107  
   sample_12           0.379291           0.292484  
   sample_24           0.045177           0.645828  
   sample_14           0.841024           0.989135  ,
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1)},
 'proteomics': {'proteomics_df': (           protein_1  protein_2  protein_3  protein_4  protein_5  protein_6  \
   sample_1    0.955152   0.694325   0.364086   0.202788   0.097524   0.056196   
   sample_12   0.151082   0.511486   0.305277   0.853249   0.590934   0.599954   
   sample_24   0.464141   0.455040   1.000000   0.695056   0.000000   0.832736   
   sample_14   0.973062   0.490422   0.473659   0.841894   0.165324   0.938762   
   
              protein_7  protein_8  protein_9  protein_10  protein_11  \
   sample_1    0.213482   0.642774   0.860823    0.192356    0.604885   
   sample_12   0.430857   0.736668   0.905799    0.709556    0.047022   
   sample_24   0.375415   0.000128   0.514156    0.000000    0.317056   
   sample_14   0.000000   0.612403   0.840148    0.936548    0.122842   
   
              protein_12  protein_13  protein_14  protein_15  protein_16  \
   sample_1     0.789842    0.749248    0.173369    0.574714    0.224573   
   sample_12    0.198308    0.785320    0.200742    0.859185    0.574507   
   sample_24    0.608147    0.000000    0.464958    0.031869    0.867148   
   sample_14    1.000000    0.817525    0.673992    0.530185    0.072392   
   
              protein_17  protein_18  protein_19  protein_20  
   sample_1     0.000000    0.866899    0.787449    0.977767  
   sample_12    0.437770    0.790534    0.786136    0.040557  
   sample_24    0.556489    0.555899    0.631475    0.784678  
   sample_14    0.978306    0.869219    0.668210    0.510911  ,
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1)},
 'mutation': {'mutation_df': (           gene_1  gene_2  gene_3  gene_4  gene_5  gene_6  gene_7  gene_8  \
   sample_1        1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0   
   sample_12       1       1       1       0       1       0       1       1   
   sample_24       1       1       1       0       1       1       0       1   
   sample_14       0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1   
   
              gene_9  gene_10  gene_11  gene_12  gene_13  gene_14  gene_15  \
   sample_1        1        0        0        1        1        0        0   
   sample_12       0        0        0        0        0        0        1   
   sample_24       1        0        0        0        1        0        0   
   sample_14       0        0        0        1        0        1        0   
   
              gene_16  gene_17  gene_18  gene_19  gene_20  
   sample_1         1        1        0        1        1  
   sample_12        1        1        1        0        1  
   sample_24        1        0        1        0        0  
   sample_14        0        1        1        0        0  ,
              Overall_Survival  Immune_Response
   sample_1                  1                0
   sample_12                 1                1
   sample_24                 1                0
   sample_14                 1                1)}}
```

Expected output:

```
[array([[ 0.864448  ,  0.09106825,  0.0082447 , -0.0076334 ,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.0123347 ,  0.675261  ,  0.00220489, -0.01955885,  1.        ,
          1.        ],
        [ 0.68785916,  0.4070271 ,  0.00220489, -0.01955885,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.84405358,  0.21946786,  0.0034894 , -0.01062435,  1.        ,
          1.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.71182397,  0.49046602, -0.04656617,  0.01624478,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.73725949,  0.09712671, -0.04680103,  0.01629315,  1.        ,
          1.        ],
        [ 1.16152444,  0.13353929, -0.04656617,  0.01624478,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.00343417,  1.11564544, -0.04656617,  0.01624478,  1.        ,
          1.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.57277066,  0.59834198,  0.0092362 , -0.00443665,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 1.09969277,  0.11959057,  0.00127037,  0.01597666,  1.        ,
          1.        ],
        [ 0.27207849,  0.53464324,  0.0021995 ,  0.01358635,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.01119349,  0.89636409,  0.00915146, -0.00429858,  1.        ,
          1.        ]]),
 array([[ 0.13387474,  0.77731093, -0.01087093,  0.00490979,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.65884812,  0.16525756, -0.01344247,  0.01440006,  1.        ,
          1.        ],
        [ 0.85281024,  0.00124021, -0.01311089,  0.01317636,  1.        ,
          0.        ],
        [ 0.33406365,  0.94603438, -0.01087093,  0.00490979,  1.        ,
          1.        ]]),
 array([[ 4.27433650e-01,  4.17119969e-01,  3.60380299e-02,
          8.52390565e-03,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 6.57250876e-02,  1.00090599e+00,  4.33478281e-02,
          1.09503735e-02,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00],
        [ 6.07513696e-01,  7.01521419e-04, -9.22964886e-04,
         -1.34556619e-02,  1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 3.49968501e-01,  8.32643489e-01,  5.40617704e-02,
          1.45068392e-02,  1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]]),
 array([[ 1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  1        ,
          0        ,  0        ,  0        ,  1        ,  0        ,
          0        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
          1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  1        ,  1        ,
         0,  0,  1        ,  0        ],
        [ 1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  1       ,  1        ,
          1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
          0        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,  0        ,
          1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
         0,  0,  1        ,  1        ],
        [ 1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  1        ,
          0        ,  0        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,
          0        ,  0        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
          1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  1        ,
         0,  0,  1        ,  0        ],
        [ 0        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  1        ,
          1        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
          0        ,  0        ,  0        ,  1        ,  0        ,
          0        ,  1        ,  1        ,  0        ,  0        ,
         0,  0,  1.        ,  1        ]])]
```

Comment: You should post your imports so we have a complete working code sample to work with and don't have to guess which libraries you're using.